# load dynamic content in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

### load dynamic content in bootstrap modal

I have created bootstrap modal which display the youtube iframe via json object

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" data-id="" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="iframe" src="" class="video-demntion"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where i frame is loaded from attribute

```
if(msg.msg_type=="video"){
                var imgList= "";
                $.each(msg.video.videos, function(index){
                     $('#iframe').attr('src','https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/' + this.video_id);
                    console.log("data-id : " + this.id );                       
                    imgList += '<li><a class="openBtn" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + this.id +'"><img src= "' + this.thumbnail_2 + '"></a></li>';
                    console.log(this.video_id);                     
                });
                $('#messages').append(imgList);
            }else{
                console.log(msg);
            }
```

**JSON**

```
Video:[videos:[{id: "23",video_id: "xa-4mQtwasI",},{id: "24",video_id:"trgr0Ya6D24",}]]
```

Jquery Onclick Funtion

```
$("a").click(function(){
                    $('#iframe').attr('src','https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/' + this.video_id);
                    $('#myModal').attr('data-id',this.id);
                    alert(this.video_id);
                    $("iframe").each(function(){
                        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
                    });
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
```

on click of anchor need to prepare the modal Basically ,the code is not firing a click function , because dom is already created i want to force the class to bind it dynamically ,from this code only last video is rendering in all modal.please correct me where i am going wrong

Comment: plz post your onclick of anchor function with this.

Comment: @Rahul Sahu I have edited the anchor funtion